# Generate Doctrine entities from database but not overwriting custom code in current Entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Following: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html

The command: `php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import "App\Entity" annotation --path=src/Entity` overwrites current `Entity/*` files, instead of just updating them with new columns from the database.

What is the standard method for updating entities pragmatically from the database without overwriting custom functions / logic in the existing Entity files?

Answer (score 0):

```
php bin/console make:entity --regenerate
```

Seems to help in regenerating the entity from the db without overwrite.